# How do you print a page from the firefox addon sdk?

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I'm trying to write a simple addon that will print all the open tabs (they will be local HTML files) using either the installed acrobat or adobe pdf writer printers. I'm hoping to be able to supply the output file name as well since it will be based on the HTML file name. All google seems to want to show me on this are links to pdf printing addon replacements for adobe.